# Prove that the intersection of A and B is normal in AB

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I was hoping to have my proof verified for correctness. Thanks in advance!

**Problem:**

If A is an abelian subgroup of G where A is also normal, and B is any subgroup of G, prove that A $\bigcap$ B is a normal subgroup of AB.

**Solution:**

Let A be a normal abelian subgroup of G. 
Let B be any subgroup of G. 
Then A $\bigcap$ B is a subgroup of G as well as it is the intersection of two subgroups of G.
Note that since A is normal and B $\le$ N$_G$(A), we have that BA $\le$ G. Since BA is a subgroup, we also have that AB = BA.

Then let z $\in$ A $\bigcap$ B.

Then ba(z)(ba)$^{-1}$ = ba(z)a$^{-1}$b$^{-1}$ = b(a$_{\alpha}$)b$^{-1}$ where a$_{\alpha}$ = aza$^{-1}$ $\in$ A.

So since A is normal we have that b(a$_{\alpha}$)b$^{-1}$ $\in$ A.

Also consider that ba(z)a$^{-1}$b$^{-1}$ = baa$^{-1}$zb$^{-1}$ = bzb$^{-1}$ $\in$ B.

Hence we have that ba(z)(ba)$^{-1}$ $\in$ A $\bigcap$ B. Hence since z was an arbitrary element of A $\bigcap$ B and ba was an arbitrary element of BA=AB, we have that A $\bigcap$ B is a normal subgroup of BA = AB.

Comment: I see no fault, your proof is correct as to me. What is crucial here is the abelian- ness of $A \leqslant G.$ How about if $A$ is not abelian as a subgroup?

Comment: At the end of line 6 of the solution you have a $b^{-1}$when I think you mean $a^{-1}$. Also although it is clear, If you are a student you might still want to mention/confirm/acknowledge that $A \cap B \leq AB $.

Comment: @fourier1234, thanks for correcting that typo, u are correct it should have been aza^{-1}...... my note on your other point would be: the intersection of A and B would be a subgroup of AB since it is a subgroup of G and it is a subset of AB, hence it is a subgroup of AB. Sound ok?

Comment: Yeh sounds fine. It is a very minor point anyway but if I was marking a students work I think I would be expecting them to acknowledge that.